# How to make my Ubuntu 16.04 system display a to-do reminder?

Tags: 16.04, notification, at-command

Sometimes I get interrupted while programming and would like to have some sort of alarm function that can remind me to do sometihing important.

I do not want to build a clock, nor do I want the kind of thing my smartphone does.

Just an on-screen reminder would be best.  Non-recurring.  I know there used to be a program called reminder that would do this.  I also know about sticky-notes but have a policy of never changing my repositories for any reason. Also there is one called something like remindor but it won't work with 16.04 LTS.

So now I can't locate anything similar.

Maybe someone in the community knows this.

How can I make my Ubuntu do this easily?  Hopefully with just a single command (because this is usually in response to a phone call for help elsewhere).

---EDIT:  I had to actually install the at command on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
sudo aptitude install at
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `xpad` or `notify-send Reminder:XXX`

Comment: Maybe a better one would be `echo 'notify-send "FINISH THAT MIDNIGHT PROGRAM"' | at 20:00`

Comment: OK, I see how that notify-send works.  It even appears on all the multiple desktops.  However, it only stays on the screen for a brief few seconds, and is silent, so there must be some command-line switches (https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/#hints) I need to look at.   But this is on the right track.  I can see how it would be handy to let a cron job send a progress message. 
 Excellent.

Comment: @SDsolar I think you are looking for `-u critial`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one that does the pop-up notifications.  It will work from the command line, and even works in cron jobs.

The simplest way to use it is like so:

```
echo 'notify-send "FINISH THAT MIDNIGHT PROGRAM"' | at 20:00
```

(Thank you, @M. Becerra)

It presents a pop-up in the upper right of all the desktops but without command-line parameters it is silent and goes away in just a few seconds, so here is a good article that explains the high points:

[Gnome Desktop Notifications Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/#hints)

It can make noises if necessary, for instance.

Comment: Also, if you need to run it in time relative to now, to can do something like this: `echo 'notify-send "FINISH THAT MIDNIGHT PROGRAM"' | at \`date -d '+1 minute' '+%H:%M'\` `

Comment: Can I schedule something on a daily basis, again using command line, as above?

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called `xpad` that works from the command line and from the GUI. Install it like this:

```
sudo apt install xpad
```

Then to run it, type

```
xpad
```

It pops up a yellow sticky-note-like window so I can keep that on-screen to remind me to call the boss when I get back, or to finish something I was working on.

It can be locked to the taskbar in case it needs to be minimized. Also, when closed entirely, it comes back with the text intact. That's a plus.

Looks like it will be useful.

But I still need something that will pop up and interrupt me at a set time, whether as a one-off or as a daily cron.

Answer (score 0):

A utility program that will pop-up reminders is Day Planner (http://www.day-planner.org)

The developer's web site states:  "Day Planner is a program designed to help you easily plan and manage your time. It can manage appointments, birthdays and more and makes sure you remember your appointments by displaying reminders."

Answer (score 0):

#### Xterm can show a dingy little black reminder window... but it stays up until you close it, unlike notify-send.

This one-liner reads a line from the terminal, then displays the reminder in xterm after sleeping for ten minutes.

$ read -p 'reminder? ' e;e=`printf %q "$e"`; sleep $((60*10)) ; xterm -e bash -c "read -p $e"

#### Here's a bash one-liner using [ebay-alarm](https://github.com/kanliot/ebay-alarm)

$ ebay-alarm 10 min -- xterm -e bash -c "read -p `printf "%q" "$(read -p 'reminder? ' e;echo $e)"`"

It's hard to read because the one-liner, uses this method:
`xterm -e bash -c "script"` , but the reminder message has to be read, then escaped with printf.